# Spark scala dataframe read and show multiline json file

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read and show JSON file data in spark using Scala. I am successful in reading the file , but when I say `dataframe.show()` it throws an error. Code as below

I see that reading multiline JSON file got easier from spark version 2.2 hence using this approach.

```
import java.sql.{Date, Timestamp}
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql._


object MostTrendingVideoOnADay {

  def main(args: Array[ String ]): Unit = {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("youtube")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

val usCategory = spark.read.option("multiline", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("G:/Apache Spark/DataSets/youtube/US_category_id.json")
usCategory.printSchema()
usCategory.show()

spark.stop()
  }
}
```

JSON File:

```
{
     "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
     "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/S730Ilt-Fi-emsQJvJAAShlR6hM\"",
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
       "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ\"",
       "id": "1",
       "snippet": {
        "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
        "title": "Film & Animation",
        "assignable": true
       }
      },
      {
       "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
       "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/UZ1oLIIz2dxIhO45ZTFR3a3NyTA\"",
       "id": "2",
       "snippet": {
        "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
        "title": "Autos & Vehicles",
        "assignable": true
       }
      }
     ]
    }
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor
>   driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   file:/G:/Apache%20Spark/DataSets/youtube/US_category_id.json does not
>   exist
>       It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE
>   tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame
>   involved.
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:127)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:174)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>        Driver stacktrace:
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>         at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:245)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2861)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:637)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:596)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:605)
>         at MostTrendingVideoOnADay$.main(MostTrendingVideoOnADay.scala:21)
>         at MostTrendingVideoOnADay.main(MostTrendingVideoOnADay.scala)
>       Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/G:/Apache%20Spark/DataSets/youtube/US_category_id.json does not
>   exist
>       It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE
>   tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame
>   involved.
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:127)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:174)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: If you check properly it clearly says ` java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/G:/Apache%20Spark/DataSets/youtube/US_category_id.json does not exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in your log file `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/G:/Apache%20Spark/DataSets/youtube/US_category_id.json does not exist`

You can see there is a space in path `Apache%20Spark` which is causing the issue can you remove the space in the path?
Make it like `ApacheSpark` or `Apache_Spark` this should solve the issue.

Hope this helps!